# How would you assign read-only permissions to run ls -l /proc/{pid}/fd for processes you don't own

Tags: permissions, security

How would you assign read-only permissions to run

```
ls -l /proc/{PID}/fd
```

for PIDs (processes) you running as another user.

Ideally, you wouldn't be able to do anything else and you would not have any additional privileges other than be able to read these paths for all other users on the machine --

I'm guessing this isn't possible unless you are root.

Comment: As far as I know, you need `root` to assign that as read-only

Answer (score 2):

You actually can't set permissions for many entries in procfs (in Linux at least) at all - they are handled by the kernel itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like this you'll have to use a restricted sudo rule (like this):

```
 user   ALL=(root) /bin/ls -l /proc/*
```

using the sudoers command (as root of course :-)1023)

The "user" would then type in:

```
 sudo /bin/ls -l /proc/....
```

to get the information.